# How does R calculates convergence tolerance and what does it stands for?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, convergence, likelihood

I'm using R for the first time for estimating parameters of a vector function. In the summary of the method I used (nls to be precise), the information on "achieved convergence tolerance" appeared. 
Is this the maximum log of the likelihood function or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I discussed this topic with my tutor (although he isn't a statistician, but a Math graduate).

He convinced me that "achieved convergence tolerance" discribes that a local minimum of a function (hier in sence of Least Square Problem) using gradient descent has been achieved (concidering the given TOL)

Hope this helps those, who wondered the same!

Comment: For a start, it's not using gradient descent, so that's not quite correct. The tolerance does try to detect a local minimum, by comparing the gradient to the residual sum of squares (and for that reason `nls` does badly in situations where the residual sum of squares at minimum is nearly zero)